# Query including TOP and AVG

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

This is the last problem I have to deal with in my application and I hope someone will help because I'm clueless, I did my research and cannot find a proper solution.

I have an 'University Administration' application. I need to make a report with few tables included.

The problem is in SQL Query i have to finish. Query needs to MAKE LIST OF BEST 'n' STUDENTS, and the condition for student to be 'best' is grade AVERAGE.

I have 3 columns (students.stID & examines.grades). I need to get an average of my 'examines.grades' column, sort the table from highest (average grade) to the lowest, and I need to filter 'n' best 'averages'.

The user would enter the filter number and as I said, the app needs to show 'n' best averages.

Problem is in my SQL knowledge (not mySQL literaly but T-SQL). This is what I've donne with my SQL query, but the problem lies in the "SELECT TOP" because when I press my button, the app takes average only from TOP 'n' rows selected.

```
SELECT TOP(@topParam) student.ID, AVG(examines.grades)
FROM            examines INNER JOIN
                         student ON examines.stID = student.stID
WHERE        (examines.grades > 1)
```

For example:

```
StudentID  Grade
1          2
2          5
1          5
2          2
2          4
2          2
```

EXIT:

```
StudentID  Grade_Average
1          3.5
2          3.25
```

Comment: Please supply example data and desired results.

Comment: Yes, please provide some example data as a query, that would help a lot. But I'm thinking that you could potentially do everything with windowed functions here.

Comment: OK. I'll do that, wait a second please

Comment: I don't know where to update my question for you to be able see clearly. Here in comment it's too bad to place my example

Comment: See here: http://prntscr.com/7j9r7c

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/nzt7g0fr9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being impatient, I think this is what you are looking for. You didn't specify which SQL Server version you're using although.

```
DECLARE @topParam INT = 3;      -- Default

DECLARE @student TABLE (StudentID INT);     -- Just for testing purpose
DECLARE @examines TABLE (StudentID INT, Grades INT);

INSERT INTO @student (StudentID) VALUES (1), (2);

INSERT INTO @examines (StudentID, Grades)
VALUES (1, 2), (2, 5), (1, 5), (2, 2), (2, 4), (2, 2);

SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@topParam) s.StudentID, AVG(CAST(e.grades AS FLOAT)) OVER (PARTITION BY s.StudentID) AS AvgGrade
FROM @examines AS e
INNER JOIN @student AS s
    ON e.StudentID = s.StudentID
WHERE e.grades > 1
ORDER BY AvgGrade DESC;
```

If you'll provide some basic data, I'll adapt query for your needs.

Result:

```
StudentID   AvgGrade
--------------------
1           3.500000
2           3.250000
```

**Quick explain:**

Query finds grades average in derived table and later queries it sorting by it. Another tip: You could use `WITH TIES` option in `TOP` clause to get more students if there would be multiple students who could fit for 3rd position.

If you'd like to make procedure as I suggested in comments, use this snippet:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetTopStudents
(
    @topParam INT = 3
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY    
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@topParam) s.StudentID, AVG(CAST(e.grades AS FLOAT)) OVER (PARTITION BY s.StudentID) AS AvgGrade
        FROM examines AS e
        INNER JOIN student AS s
            ON e.StudentID = s.StudentID
        WHERE e.grades > 1
        ORDER BY AvgGrade DESC;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH
END
```

And later call it like that. It's a good way to encapsulate your logic.

```
EXEC dbo.GetTopStudents @topParam = 3;
```

Comment: It's quite detailed example. I'll need some time to go through all of this and will get back to you. Thank you very much

Comment: No problems, keep in mind that solution provided by suslov should work just fine too. So it's just a matter of performance and taste (if they both perform well).

Comment: Your query works but I have 2 problems now. First - my reportViewer doesn't recognize AvGrade, I don't get any result in my reportViewer. Second - I get right results in QUERY BUILDER but the average numbers are integer, and for AVG (2&5) I get 3 and not 3.50 as I should. Can you help me with dat

Comment: Are you sure you used correct alias, it's called `AvgGrade` and not `AvGrade`, maybe it's that? and for decimal places, i've updated question, perhaps casting it as a float would help? And if your reportViewer doesn't recognize it, perhaps it would be a good idea to make `Stored Procedure` out of it and pass @topParam as parameter?

Comment: I gave you correct, but my reportViewer still doesnt work. Whole day of work and my head is full. I'll go to sleap and restart tomorrow.thank you very much. You'll probably hear from me

Comment: I don't have any experience with `reportViewer` unfortunately. But perhaps this could be something helpful for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794360/report-viewer-control-send-parameter-to-stored-procedure-in-dataset

Answer (score 1):

You should use  the `group by` clause for counting average grades (in case `examines.grades` has an integer type, you should `cast` it to the floating-point type) for each `student.ID` and `order by` clause to limit your output to only `top` n with *highest* average grades:

```sql
select top(@topParam) student.ID
     , avg(cast(examines.grades as float)) as avg_grade
from examines
join student on examines.stID = student.stID
where (examines.grades > 1)
group by student.ID
order by avg_grade desc
```

Comment: @user5028260: Are you running the query without parenthesis around `@topParam`? There was an edit.

Comment: For edited code I get "UNABLE TO PARSE QUERY TEXT".

I'm doing the code in query builder, which will then I 'call' on reportViewer

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for A Windowed Aggregate which returns the duplicate rows and then you need DISTINCT to remove them again. It's a simple aggregation and your original query was already quite close:

```
SELECT TOP(@topParam) student.ID, AVG(CAST(grade AS FLOAT)) as AvgGrade
FROM            examines INNER JOIN
                         student ON examines.stID = student.stID
WHERE        (examines.grades > 1)
group by student.ID
order by AvgGrade DESC
```